# Angular form submission is not working in ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs

If i submit a form in ng repeat loop then form value is not passed.

```
<li ng-repeat="com in post.comments">{{ com.body }}        
       <h4>Reply</h4>
       <form ng-submit="addReply()">
           <textarea name="rbody" ng-model="rbody">    </textarea>                            
           <button type="submit">Reply</button>
       </form>    
   </li>
```

in Controller :

```
$scope.addReply = function(){
    console.log($scope.rbody);
};
```

But If i keep the form outside of loop then then I get value in console. What's the problem in my code

Comment: remove form tag in n-repeat and write ng-click="addReply(com.id)" in reply button. **com.id**  is dynamic. use only 1 form tag outside the list tag

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single istance of your `$scope.rbody`variable: hence, it's getting replaced on every iteration of ng-repeat.

To fix this issue, simply attach the `ng-model` of the form to the current ng-repeat iteration, for example:

```
<li ng-repeat="com in post.comments">{{ com.body }}        
   <h4>Reply</h4>
   <form ng-submit="addReply(com)">
       <textarea name="rbody" ng-model="com.rbody"></textarea>                            
       <button type="submit">Reply</button>
  </form>    
</li>
```

then in your controller you will be able to get every inserted value of your array:

```
$scope.addReply = function(comObj){
    console.log(comObj.rbody);
};
```